# How much length can be of a Telegram user_id?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot, lua-telegram-bot

*I am making a database in which my algorithm only accepts queries from users with telegram id length of 9.*

```
user_id: 123456789;
length = user_id.length;
display(length);

OUTPUT: 9
```

*Are there telegram user ids of length lesser than 9?*
*Can anybody suggest something, so that i can update my algorithm to length of that ids too.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can refer to [Contact](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#contact) section of API document.

> it has at most 52 significant bits, so a 64-bit integer or double-precision float type are safe for storing this identifier.

---

### 2018 (Outdated):

There have no known limit of user ID, but I know there have some user have less than 9 digits ID.

For instance, @MarkusRa have 6-digits ID.

The maximum length I have seen is 9 digits, and starts with `6`, it seems to increase by time, maybe it will have 10 digits soon

Comment: official Telegram account's ID is also 6 digits number:777000

Comment: Currently Telegram account's ID MAX length is 10 in 2022 the length might increase as the users increase

Answer (score 10):

> Unique identifier for this chat. This number may be greater than 32 bits and some programming languages may have difficulty/silent defects in interpreting it. But it is smaller than 52 bits, so a **signed 64 bit integer** or **double-precision float** type are safe for storing this identifier.

[Telegram Bot API#Chat](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#chat)

Answer (score 2):

I have seen 10 digits user ID starts with 5, it exceeds int32 max value.

Answer (score 0):

Today I saw two guys who have a double-digit ID

@Ruslan_Ozdoev : 25
@Akhmedoff_J : 55

(6 Digit)
@MarkusRa : 914597